# Search for a string in multiple text files and print the file name that the string is in

Tags: python

I need to search for a certain keyword within several text files and need to print out the names of the text files that have that certain keyword in it.

So far I have this but I am not sure how to print the name of the files that the keyword is in. Can someone please assist?

```
with open("result.txt", "w") as resultfile:
    for result in [txt for txt in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if txt.endswith(".txt")]:
        if 'keyword' in open(result).read():
             resultfile.write('string is in file {1}')
        else:
             resultfile.write('NOT {0}')
```

Comment: You have the file name as the loop index, `result`.  If you do not know how to print the variable value, please refer to any tutorial on `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work. The for loop is running through the filenames in the current working directory, so the current iteration is the current filename.

```
with open("result.txt", "w") as resultfile:
    for result in [txt for txt in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if txt.endswith(".txt")]:
        if 'keyword' in open(result).read():
             resultfile.write('string is in file %s' % result)
        else:
             resultfile.write('NOT %s' % result)
```